# A set of elements limited by the largest element of another set?

Tags: multisets

I am trying to mathematically express a set of elements 'A' limited by the largest value in another set 'B'.

I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Is $\{x\in A : x \leq \max(B)\}$ what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, Benguin. I think this makes sense. Since I don't know the right expression, other ideas are also welcome.